# Future Unformed chopped up audio effect?

Tags: game-audio, sound-effects

I always wondered how they make the Syder Arcade chopped up sound effect in the beginning of "The Future Unformed"?  I have Audition... but I'd also appreciate learning what they are doing to the sound. Are they deleting the beginning of every word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, a vocoder is being used to get the robotic effect from the vocal sample. It sounds like the filter bands of the vocoder are being swept at the start. Or maybe it is a separate filter sweep(like a comb filter). You can't really tell how the vocals are being cut up unless you know what it sounded like originally. But it is most probably chopped into a rhythm or sampled or played back rhythmically through a keyboard or manipulated by a pulse wave LFO. There are many ways to get that result. I also hear a bitcrusher (with random-stepped LFO modulation (?)) in there somewhere.